# Question in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I need help with this problem.

> Show that a Cauchy sequence in $[0,1]$ must converge to a point of $[0,1]$.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know that every Cauchy sequence converges in the reals?  Can a Cauchy sequence in $[0,1]$ converge outside $[0,1]$?

Comment: sorry you are wrong not every Cauchy sequence converge

Comment: Actually.... he's right.

Comment: theorem said a convergent sequence is Cauchy

Comment: The theorem didn't say that the converse is not true, did it?

Comment: it could be but not always because you can find cauchy sequence which is not converge to (0,1) Am I right ?

Comment: @leenaadam in $\mathbb R$, every Cauchy sequence converges.

Comment: thank you for helping thank you for answer but can you please explain little more also can we use contraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a Cauchy sequence converges outside $[0,1]$.  So $x_n$ is Cauchy in $[0,1]$ and converges to $x \notin [0,1]$.  If $x > 1$, then take $x - 1 > 0$, and if $x < 0$, take $-x >0$.

Take $0 < \epsilon < -x$ or $0 < \epsilon < x-1$ (depending on the cases above).  Since $x_n \to x$, then $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ for $n \ge N$ for some $N$.  If $x > 1$, then $|x_n - x| \ge x - 1 > \epsilon$, which is a contradiction.  If $x < 0$, then $|x_n - x| \ge -x > \epsilon$, which is a contradiction.

But since $x_n \to x$, for some $x$ (since every *real* Cauchy sequence converges), $x$ must be in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

In the real numbers every Cauchy sequence converges to some real number (this property is essentially equivalent to the completeness of the real numbers). A proof sketch is: A Cauchy sequence is bounded, thus, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, it has a convergent subsequence (this is the completeness bit actually). For a Cauchy sequence, the limit of a convergent subsequence must actually be the limit of the entire sequence.

Now, you probably proved that weak limits are preserved by when passing to the limit. That is, if a sequence $a_n$ converges to $a$, and $a_n\le t$, then $a\le t$. Similarly for inequalities in the other direction. So now, you have a sequence in $[0,1]$ which is Cauchy. So it converges to some point. But by preservation of weak inequalities, the limit point $a$ satisfies $a\in [0,1]$.